# SKRouteManager.getInstance().calculateRoute(route); return nullpointer exception in SKMaps SDK 2.4

Tags: android, skmaps

I am able to get SKMaps initialized and display the map in my MapsActivity.
The problem is that my app crashes with a nullpointer exception whenever it tries to calculated a route.

Right now the code has the Advisorsettings set by tapping the map which is only for testing purposes since I wanted to make sure it set those settings before calculating the route, which is launched by double tap also testing purposes.

I have read that the Skobbler SDK 2.4 had problems with this and the advisorSettings had to be set to make it work but this wont help me.

Any ideas why launchRouteCalculation() crashes??
Should I just revert back to SDK 2.3 or is there a fix?

TO CLARIFY: SKRouteManager.getInstance().calculateRoute(route); makes it crash.

```
    public class MapsActivity extends Activity implements SKMapSurfaceListener, SKRouteListener {

/**
 * Surface view for displaying the map
 */
private SKMapSurfaceView mapView;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    SKMapViewHolder mapHolder = (SKMapViewHolder)
            findViewById(R.id.map_surface_holder);
    mapView = mapHolder.getMapSurfaceView();
    mapView.setMapSurfaceListener(this);
    SKRouteManager.getInstance().setRouteListener(MapsActivity.this);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Loading Map...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    mapView.getMapSettings().setCurrentPositionShown(true);
    mapView.setZoom(20);
   /*
    Button navBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.navBtn);
    navBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked the button...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    */

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mapView.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mapView.onResume();
}


@Override
public void onActionPan() {

}

@Override
public void onActionZoom() {

}

@Override
public void onSurfaceCreated() {
    //System.out.print("Surface created");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Map loaded! Yeey!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

@Override
public void onScreenOrientationChanged() {

}

@Override
public void onMapRegionChanged(SKCoordinateRegion skCoordinateRegion) {

}

@Override
public void onMapRegionChangeStarted(SKCoordinateRegion skCoordinateRegion) {

}

@Override
public void onMapRegionChangeEnded(SKCoordinateRegion skCoordinateRegion) {

}

@Override
public void onDoubleTap(SKScreenPoint skScreenPoint) {

    launchRouteCalculation();
    }


@Override
public void onSingleTap(SKScreenPoint skScreenPoint) {
    String mapResDirPath;
    File externalDir = getExternalFilesDir(null);

    // determine path where map resources are

    if (externalDir != null) {
        mapResDirPath = externalDir + "/SKMaps/";
    } else {
        mapResDirPath = getFilesDir() + "/SKMaps/";
    }

    final SKAdvisorSettings advisorSettings = new SKAdvisorSettings();
    advisorSettings.setLanguage(SKAdvisorSettings.SKAdvisorLanguage.LANGUAGE_EN);
    advisorSettings.setAdvisorConfigPath(mapResDirPath + "/SKMaps/Advisor/");
    advisorSettings.setResourcePath(mapResDirPath + "/SKMaps/Advisor/Languages/");
    advisorSettings.setAdvisorVoice("en");
    advisorSettings.setAdvisorType(SKAdvisorSettings.SKAdvisorType.AUDIO_FILES);
    SKRouteManager.getInstance().setAudioAdvisorSettings(advisorSettings);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),advisorSettings.getAdvisorVoice(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked the map! Yeey!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onRotateMap() {

}

@Override
public void onLongPress(SKScreenPoint skScreenPoint) {

}

@Override
public void onInternetConnectionNeeded() {

}

@Override
public void onMapActionDown(SKScreenPoint skScreenPoint) {

}

@Override
public void onMapActionUp(SKScreenPoint skScreenPoint) {

}

@Override
public void onPOIClusterSelected(SKPOICluster skpoiCluster) {

}

@Override
public void onMapPOISelected(SKMapPOI skMapPOI) {

}

@Override
public void onAnnotationSelected(SKAnnotation skAnnotation) {

}

@Override
public void onCustomPOISelected(SKMapCustomPOI skMapCustomPOI) {

}

@Override
public void onCompassSelected() {

}

@Override
public void onCurrentPositionSelected() {

}

@Override
public void onObjectSelected(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onInternationalisationCalled(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onBoundingBoxImageRendered(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onGLInitializationError(String s) {

}

public void launchRouteCalculation() {
    // get a route settings object and populate it with the desired properties
    SKRouteSettings route = new SKRouteSettings();
    // set start and destination points
    route.setStartCoordinate(new SKCoordinate(57.708266, 11.935341));
    route.setDestinationCoordinate(new SKCoordinate(57.715098, 11.945383));
    // set the number of routes to be calculated
    route.setNoOfRoutes(1);
    // set the route mode
    route.setRouteMode(SKRouteSettings.SKRouteMode.CAR_FASTEST);
    // set whether the route should be shown on the map after it's computed
    route.setRouteExposed(true);
    // set the route listener to be notified of route calculation
    // events
    SKRouteManager.getInstance().setRouteListener(this);
    // pass the route to the calculation routine
    SKRouteManager.getInstance().calculateRoute(route);

}


@Override
public void onRouteCalculationCompleted(SKRouteInfo skRouteInfo) {

}

@Override
public void onRouteCalculationFailed(SKRoutingErrorCode skRoutingErrorCode) {

}

@Override
public void onAllRoutesCompleted() {

}

@Override
public void onServerLikeRouteCalculationCompleted(SKRouteJsonAnswer skRouteJsonAnswer) {

}

@Override
public void onOnlineRouteComputationHanging(int i) {

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

For 2.4, the workaround will be to use SKRouteManager.getInstance().getAdviceList(). Set the advisorSettings and let the Advisor folder in SKMaps.zip (with the needed config files).
In 2.5 you will have the possibility to remove advisorSettings and the app won't crash anymore.